# Codeigniter unable to load library class

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a library file named `myMenu.php`

```
<?php
class myMenu{
    function show_menu()
    {
        $obj = & get_instance();
        $obj->load->helper('url');

        $menu = "<ul>";

        $menu .= "<li>";
        $menu .= anchor('books/index','List of books');
        $menu .= "</li>";

        $menu .= "<li>";
        $menu .= anchor('books/input','Books entry');
        $menu .= "</li>";

        $menu .= "</ul>";

        return $menu;
    }
}
```

Now I loaded this library in my controller `books.php`

```
function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('myMenu');
        $menu = new myMenu;
        $data['menu'] = $menu->show_menu();
        $this->load->view('main_view',$data);
    }
```

But the page shows error `An error occurred : Unable to load the requested class: mymenu`. Why this error is showing class name as  `mymenu` (all in lowercase) wherein I wrote `myMenu` at controller

Comment: PHP is case-insensitive in this regard. Class case shouldn't matter: http://codepad.org/swAK8iuh

Comment: Is the file name capitalized?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two problems:

1) Your naming convention is wrong.

In CodeIgniter, libraries must start with a capitalized letter.
The class name and file name both have to start with capital letters, and they have to match.
Refer to the document below.
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

2) You shouldn't instantiate myMenu with `new`.
When accessing a library which you loaded, this is pretty much the usual way:

```
    $this->load->library('mymenu'); // when calling the loader, the case doesn't matter
    $data['menu'] = $this->mymenu->show_menu(); //'mymenu' is the lowercase of the class name
```

Comment: This was helpful as I was running into an issue where I did have class name capitalized but not the file name. Thus, my code would run fine on Windows but not on a Linux server.

Answer (score 1):

Class name should be capitalized. `class MyMenu`

Comment: @WaleedKhan In traditional PHP it is allowed, but the CodeIgniter library has a naming convention, and requires us to capitalize the class name.

Comment: @ashiina After checking `system/core/Loader.php` at `_ci_init_class` and `_ci_load_library`, I couldn't find any evidence that the class name actually has to be capitalized.

Comment: @WaleedKhan I couldn't actually find ``_ci_load_library`` so we might be in a different version. Even so, it might not produce any direct errors at this moment, but it is a convention stated in the official document. The code can be fixed at any version update to follow the official document, and when that happens your system fails. Following the official document's requirements is a habit we all should try to follow.